# Applied maven surefire test conventions but appcenter returns exit code 2

Tags: java, ios, appium, visual-studio-app-center

My appium iOS test compiles successfully locally. After uploading it to App Center I get `Cannot run tests. Returning exit code 2`. I followed the guidelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium, meaning also naming conventions for *.java* test classes (nTest.java), but the error is stil the same.
What naming thing am I missing what this exit code indicates? Here is my project tree:
[Project tree with names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmt30.png)

Thank you.

Comment: did you find the answer ?